# Performace read from file fgetc vs fread entire string

Tags: c, string, performance, file, io

I try check what is faster:

1. Calculate size of file, read entire content to string (char*), operations on string 
   VS.
2. Read char by char using fgetc and making operations on single char.

My results say there are no diffrence. What do you think?

1. What is real faster?
2. Complexity operation matters?
3. Type od hard disk matters (HDD / SSD)?
4. First case use more memory so in big files will be worse, right?
5. There is diffrence when file is small?
6. Operating system matters? (i use linux Ubuntu 14)

My code below:

Begin:

```
    size_t start = clock();
    volatile size_t some = 0;
    FILE* fh = fopen("/home/xxx/test/file.txt", "r");
```

1. case

```
    size_t size = 0;
    fseek(fh, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(fh);
    rewind(fh);
    char* result = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
    fread((void*) result, sizeof(char), size, fh);
    result[size] = '\0';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (result[i] % 2)
        {
            some++;
        }
    }

    free(result);
```

2. case

```
    int c = fgetc(fh);
    while (c != EOF)
    {
        if (c % 2)
        {
            some++;
        }

        c = fgetc(fh);
    }
```

End:

```
    fclose(fh);
    size_t end = clock();
    printf("TIME = %zu\n", end - start);
```

In my case operation is simple condition, volatile prevent compilator optimalization.

Comment: It is possible the stdio library internally read the whole string and gives it to you with fgetc one char at a time.

Comment: Reading the whole file might fail if the file is very big. Probably you need a bigger file to see a possible performance difference. If it is a text file I recommend processing it line by line (`fgets`), for binary files using a fixed block size (`fread`).

Comment: Try `getc()` instead of `fgetc()`, and compile with sufficient optimisations.

Comment: @wildplasser I dont see diffrence, maybe 1%...

Comment: Use `times your_program` to obtain the timing. (here getc() is about 10% faster)

Comment: @wildplasser You right, there is diffrence when i check time using `times` or `clock()` in program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably the reading of the file that limits the performance, the operations you do on the data have a negligible cost compared to reading the file. To make that efficient it should be best to do it in large enough chunks, so one byte at a time could in principle be bad.

However, in practice, there is probably some clever buffering going on behind the scenes. So even if your program just asks for one byte at a time, the file is in reality read in large chunks, giving you roughly the same performance as your first approach.

(The above was assuming that the reading of the file dominated the cost completely. If that was not the case, and if memory access was slow, it could happen that the one-byte-at-a-time approach could be faster since that approach avoiding accessing the same part of memory twice.)

Comment: Thanks for clear answer, i making tests with 1GB file and more operations and still no diffrence so must be some hidden buffering.